# R: addition value from one table to another by date (join the tables)

Tags: r, datetime, merge

Good day! Please help me!
I'm going to add value "Open" from table "D"("xts" "zoo") to table "d"("data.frame") by date ("index" in "D", "dateOpen" in "d"). I want to add a new column to "d" with the corresponding date. How can I do this with R?

Thank you!

```
"d"
             dateOpen priceOpen           dateClose priceClose  res cumres
1 2016-01-13 11:55:00     70670 2016-01-13 12:46:00      69853 -817   -817
2 2016-01-13 16:20:00     70670 2016-01-13 18:31:00      69853 -817  -1634
3 2016-01-14 21:55:00     70090 2016-01-14 23:49:00      69940 -150  -1784

"D"
            Open  High   Low Close  Volume
2016-01-11 16811 73560 68230 68710  656176
2016-01-12 68700 70720 67800 69050  766788
2016-01-13 69130 70930 68140 68470  798137
2016-01-14 68420 70220 67980 70060  757285
2016-01-15 69970 69970 64020 64970 1147526




    The answer is:
            dateOpen priceOpen           dateClose priceClose  res cumres Open   
1 2016-01-13 11:55:00     70670 2016-01-13 12:46:00      69853 -817   -817 69130 
2 2016-01-13 16:20:00     70670 2016-01-13 18:31:00      69853 -817  -1634 69130 
3 2016-01-14 21:55:00     70090 2016-01-14 23:49:00      69940 -150  -1784 68420
```

Comment: Matching one table to another table means you want to **_join_** the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `merge` function.

```
df <- merge(d,
            D[, c("index", "Open")],
            by.x = "dateOpen",
            by.y = "index")
```

This assumes your date column in D is named "index", that part was a bit unclear in your question.

Comment: In D date is index of time series without any name.

Comment: I understand the idea. Everything is working! Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I could help. Good luck!